# asp.net page does not display before redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web form that requests a user's user ID and domain.  It then posts information to a second page that then queries AD for info on that user ID.  I use session variables to store the info and all of that works perfectly.  What I want is to show a message via a asp:label, wait 3 seconds and then redirect.

What I have is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PreviousPage == null)
        {
            tblAccountStatus.Visible = false;
            lblUserNotFound.Text = "No user ID was submitted, redirecting back to the start page.";
            Response.BufferOutput = true;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Server.Transfer("default.aspx");
...
```

This works great but the message is not displayed.  All I get is a blank page for 3 seconds and then it redirects.  Any ideas?

Comment: try response.flush after Response.BufferOutput = true;

Comment: You should perform the redirect client side instead of server side and make the "wait" with javascript code.

Comment: Does message shows when you comment all code which is used to make redirect?

Comment: When you do `lblUserNotFound.Text = "...."` the page is not updated in *real time* - that's not how the web works. All of your code is executed and THEN the produced document is returned to the browser. By which time, you've already transferred to a different aspx page.

Comment: have you tried create new async function to wait and transfer and call that function in page_load , allows it to load the page and then transfer that page.

Comment: Thanks guys, makes sense.  The page_load renders everything and then only sends the data to the webpage.

Comment: Sorted. I created a separate HTML page with the message and the javascript to redirect after 3 seconds. So, I redirect to that page if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the wrong way. Using Thread.Sleep in Page_load you just postpone the send of page to client. I.e., client machine sends a request to server, server wait 3 seconds (this time client receives nothing and shows a blank page) and then redirects to default.aspx.

In order to show the message for a certain time you should immediately return to the client the page with your message and execute the client-side script which waits 3 seconds and then makes a redirection.

Comment: Thanks.  Now is the question, how does one add javascript and execute it from code behind.  I have added the javascript code in the aspx page.  I have tried a couple of options like page.clientscript.registerscriptblock... with no joy.

Comment: It's more simple. Write you script to MayScript.js file and include it to the page: <script type="text/javascript" src="MyScript.js"></script>

Comment: Sorted.  I created a separate HTML page with the message and the javascript to redirect after 3 seconds.  So, I redirect to that page if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain but I think it is because you are sleeping and redirecting in the Page_Load method. Try to set the text in Page_Load and then in the LoadComplete event use the thread sleep and transfer.

Comment: It will not help. The asp.net webforms round trip is "one time, one direction". Client sends request - client receives response. LoadComplete is just one more handler on server side called before the response is sent to client. Since the client received a response it's no way to send something else from server without client request.